# Receipt address won't show up in the email sent by golang smtp client

Tags: go, smtp

Here is the code snippet to send the email via a local postfix server:

```
from := r.FormValue("from")
to := strings.Split(r.FormValue("to"), ";")
body := r.FormValue("body")
mime := "MIME-version:1.0;\nContent-Type:text/html;charset=\"UTF-8\";\n\n"
subject := fmt.Sprintf("Subject: %s\n", r.FormValue("subject"))
msg := []byte(subject + mime + body)

err := smtp.SendMail("localhost:25", nil, from, to, msg)
```

The email was sent/received fine. However, it is missing the receipt address in the To field of received email. I also tried it on an exchange server. The receipt addresses are missing as well. Here is what it shows in the email source.

```
To: Undisclosed recipients:;
```

Any suggestions to fix it? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the values for the mail envelope, but you haven't put any headers in the email itself except for `Subject:`. You should also be using `\r\n` as a newline for email.

A minimal example might look like:

```
headers := make(map[string]string)

headers["Subject"] = "this is a test"
headers["From"] = "me@example.com"
headers["To"] = "you@example.com"

body := "hello,\nthis is a test"

var msg bytes.Buffer
for k, v := range headers {
    msg.WriteString(k + ": " + v + "\r\n")
}

msg.WriteString("\r\n")
msg.WriteString(body)
```

Some other helpful stdlib packages:

- [`net/textproto`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/textproto/) for MIME header handling
- [`net/mail`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/mail/) for address handling (though the package is really only for parsing email)
- http://gopkg.in/gomail.v1 for a more complete solution (there are probably many others)